# Using find to rename files recursively with random chars

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, scripting

I have an IP camera that takes snapshots and nests those snapshots into multiple directories.  The sub directories look something like this.

```
/cam_folder
   |--Date
   |----Hour
   |------Minute
   |-------->file1
   |-------->file2...etc
   |------Minute
   |-------->file1...etc
```

There is a ton of sub directories because of the way it stores files since it places those snapshots within a Minute directory of the Date/Hour directories.

At any rate, there are other types of files mixed in, but I know how to use find to find all the .jpgs I need:

```
find /cam_folder/ -type f -name '*.jpg'
```

But what I need to do is rename all the .jpg files to random characters.  I was able to find this which works from a single directory in a bash script:

```
for file in *.jpg; do
    new_file="$(mktemp XXXXXXXX.jpg)"
    mv -f -- "$file" "$new_file"
done
```

My problem is how to tie these together?  I need to use find to feed these into a bash script I guess?

Is there an easier way to just walk a directory recursively renaming as I go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /cam_folder/ -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c '
for f; do
  mv -f -- "$f" "${f%/*}/$(mktemp -u XXXXXXXX.jpg)"
done' _ {} +
```

<sub>[find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47)

[Shell Command Language § The for Loop](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_03)

[Shell Command Language § Parameter Expansions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think that meets your demand

```
while IFS= read -r file ; do 
     new_file="$(mktemp XXXXXXXX.jpg)"
     mv -f -- "$file" "$new_file"
done < <(find /cam_folder/ -type f -name '*.jpg')
```